# CAST not valid (OLEDB Date)

Tags: c#, asp.net, db2, oledb, ibm-midrange

good day. I am using an OLEDB connection to connect to DB2 database. I am having problems mapping the dates from database inside .NET.

In my business object I defined a `private DateTime _genftmdpdate=DateTime.MinValue;`
But whenever I fetch the date from database and populate inside my variable I get **Specified Cast not valid error**

```
myftModInstall.genFtMDPDate = myRecord.GetDateTime(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENFTMDPDATE"))
```

Please help me as I don't want to convert the date into string all the time.

Edit
--- This won't work as well `myftModInstall.genFtMDPDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myRecord.GetType((System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date)(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENFTMDPDATE"))));`

Answer (score 1):

The IBMDA* providers default to mapping DB2 Date data types to strings.  You must override the default in your connection string:

```
convert date time to char=FALSE
```

See this question: [Using AS400 date in SSRS Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951804/using-as400-date-in-ssrs-report)

IBM support article on connection properties: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017400

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check for a NULL before attempting to retrieve a value.

```
if(!myRecord.IsDBNull(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENFTMDPDATE"))
    myftModInstall.genFtMDPDate = myRecord.GetDateTime(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENFTMDPDATE"));
```

Comment: Hiya I have done that exactly. It does not fix the problem. The problem lies in fetching the date from datatabase 'myRecord.GetDateTime', if I change it to myRecord.GetString it works but then I have to do whole conversion to date thing.

Comment: What's the SQL data type for the database column?

Comment: In database it is of DATE type. But I can never manage to read it as date by myrecord.GetDate. GetString works only.

Comment: What do you get from `myRecord.GetFieldType(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENFTMDPDATE"))`?